# Crop screen (laptop is right side is broken)

Tags: laptop

My laptop screen is broken, only a portion of it works. Circa 2 cm of the right hand side and 1 cm of the bottom is black, because I dropped it on the floor. Of course the software does not "understand" this broken hardware. Question: Can I crop the screen so that only some part (the portion that is not black) is usable?

Comment: How is this question related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. The question is related to how I can use the OS to solve the problem with my screen.

Comment: You might need to use an external monitor.  I have not seen settings in Ubuntu itself to shift the screen over to one side or the other.